# Outlook Add-IN: Refused to display in a frame , because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We built an Outlook Add-In and got error message like below in Web version Outlook.

> Refused to display in a frame because it set to 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

We tried adding a line `add name='X-Frame-Options' value='ALLOW-FROM https://outlook.office.com` in the `web.config` to have it fixed only for email accounts from `outlook.office.com`, but still have issues for other email accounts like `outlook.live.com`.

How can it be fixed for all different email accounts?

Comment: What your add-in try to do exactly ? the add-in works with this message or it's not load at all ? Little bit more information will be great.

Comment: `sameorigin` won't work because your add-in is not hosted on `office.com` or `live.com`. I believe the `X-Frame-Options` header will need to be added more programmatically, to handle various domains. You could also look at `Content-Security-Policy` to see if that may be a bit more flexible.

Comment: Did this ever get solved? It just occurred to one of my add-ins, that had been running without issue.